# Digital save file compatibility for Bloodborne

Tags: bloodborne

So I got the vanilla version of Bloodborne when it was on PS+ and got the DLC as well but because of economical reasons I have not been able to continue with PS+. I was in the Old Hunters and my roommate still in the game but looking forward to playing the DLC as well. Since we both work we did not think getting PS+ for a short time (ie. a month or three) would be good because we know we would end up having to renew it several times. But...the complete bundle is available on the PS network for roughly the same price as three months PS+ and it would only be a one time payment. However we need to know if we could access our save files. I have seen this addressed for disk to disk and digital to disk but not when both versions are digital.

Anyone know if it would be no issue to keep playing on our files or would we have to start over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that Bloodborne work with regards to DLC and save file is like so. If the save file was created on a game that has access to the Old Hunter's DLC, the data in the save file will be *permanently altered* to show that it was created on a game with said access. When the game tries to load a save file created in this way, it runs a check to see if the DLC is installed on the device. If it finds that the DLC is not present, it will give the message:

> Unable to located Bloodborne: The Old Hunters DLC. This save data cannot be used until the DLC is downloaded again.

This message will always appear when trying to load the game *without* the DLC installed. However, this will **not** corrupt or in any way change the data in the save file.

If you do purchase The Old Hunters DLC and install it onto your device, then when the game runs the check on the save file, it *ought* to load it completely normal. It should load up the save as if the DLC was never uninstalled. No guarantee, but this this is how it should work.

For more information on someone in a similar situation, refer to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/bloodborne/comments/8zo1s9/help_cannot_load_save_from_account_that_does_not/) Reddit thread. Hope this helps and happy hunting!

Comment: Thanks @Despato! So since we do have The Old Hunters DLC installed it should be no problem if we get the Complete Bundle? She has been trying to figure it out mainly because I was so ahead. The plan is she gets the Complete Bundle and hopefully we can both access our files. Or should she get it on my PS account? Since thats the one that had downloaded the games originally.

Comment: @Scott.Bell no problem. Unfortunately, Bloodborne save files are account locked. So, for example, if  you started a save using your PS account, your account would be the only one that could access it, even if it is moved to a new machine. If your roomate started a game on your account, she couldn't move it to her account even if she got the game and DLC. However, if she started one using her own account, it should work if she has the game and DLC.

Comment: Oh each has their save files on the independent account. It was more if I have to install the game or if she buys it in her account it wouldn't be an issue. So far it seems though that we are getting this game again since it seems we would have no issue using it so thanks for the answer! Mainly from her since she has been looking around online for the answer.